# Django-twilio Discover Twilio credentials without user instance

Tags: django, twilio

I have been using django-twilio for a while now to send SMS messages to users of my application. My setup is fairly simple, quite similar to the [django-twilio docs](https://django-twilio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#authentication-token-management). I am storing the credentials inside my virtualenv  `/bin/activate.sh`.

I am then using the django-twilio `discover_twilio_credentials()` to retrieve the credentials.

```
account_sid, auth_token = discover_twilio_credentials(request.user)
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)
```

This works fine, however `discover_twilio_credentials()` is expecting a user instance passed to it. I now need to be able to send sms without the user making a post, so i need to get the twilio credentials without the user instance. The obvious solution to this would be to have a User instance which is just for getting the credentials but it doesn't seem very nice!

So does anyone know how to get `discover_twilio_credentials()` without a user instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to pass in a user instance. It seems that `discover_twilio_credentials` tries multiple ways to get Twilio creds. If you pass it a user, then it will try to find credentials specific to that user. If that fails, then it falls back to environment variables, so it should find the values from your `activate.sh` script.

https://github.com/rdegges/django-twilio/blob/master/django_twilio/utils.py#L19-L31